# pyspark dataframe takes too long to filter/transform into pandas df/ filter

Tags: python, pyspark

I am havin a pyspark dataframe which has around 120k records, I am trying to do some operations on it. some operations work so fine. but when I try to write it into csv, or transform it into pandas, or try to filter like this:

```
state_not_equal= df_h_with_distance_order_osm_P.filter(df_h_with_distance_order_osm['state'] != df_h_with_distance_order_osm['state_osm'])
```

it takse so long time and it seems stuck. even though when I tried to apply another condition on this data it worked fine:

```
df_h_with_distance_order_osm_P= df_h_with_distance_order_osm_P.filter(df_h_with_distance_order_osm_P["city"] == 'Hannover, Landeshauptstadt')
```

I tried to cache the dataframe and persist it but no luck, any idea what I can do or check please?

update:

I added these lines to the config of the cluster of spark in databricks

```
spark.executor.memoryOverhead 4g
spark.executor.instances 4
spark.executor.memory 16g
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions 100
```

and I even just set the writing limit to 4 as follows:

```
df_h_with_distance_order_osm.limit(4).write.csv("/FileStore/tables/final_s.csv")
```

and it's still stuck, even though when I did .show() it is shown.
also, I want to mention that the same issue appears when I try to run on colab pro.
please help

update again:

when I tried to write only 4 rows it succeeded, but when I tried to make them 500 rows for example it still stuck i am not sure what to do

Comment: `spark.executor.memory` - You can try to increase the memory while configuring the spark session builder creation or try `repartition() ` the dataframe

Comment: thanks for your answer, i already tried reparttition but with no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Can you add more about the infrastructure and configuration that you are trying to execute on like hardware settings or environment, because, I guess,you can improve the level of parallelism by configuring the number of executor cores and partitions to optimize the write process.

Comment: I am using databricks, my cluster is 32GB and 4 cores. how can I configure the parralleization plz? and also in the filter not just writing?

Comment: `spark.executor.instances-4` `spark.executor.memory 8g` `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true` `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 100)` - May be you can set these Databricks workspavce  in cluster with  spark configs.

Comment: check the transformations applied from source to `df_h_with_distance_order_osm_P`. the transformations might be complex and, thus, taking time when an action is executed.